# AHK WinActivate not able to exclude

Tags: autohotkey

I just want to exclude Google Chrome in a WinActivate. I've tried everything from fully qualifying the title of the window to using variables, strings, none of this works. It always switches to chrome because I have two windows open that match the string string -- Chrome and Windows Explorer. I want to switch to windows explorer.

```
Ticket_Out := "00123456"
xclude:= Ticket_Out . "00123456 | Salesforce - Google Chrome"

WinActivate % Ticket_Out,, xclude, ; doesn't work
WinActivate, "00123456",, "00123456 | Salesforce - Google Chrome", ; also doesn't work
```

I know there is a WinActivateBottom but I really want to avoid using this. I really just would like the exclude to work. What's wrong with my syntax or my command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every parameter in any command (unless otherwise specified) uses legacy syntax.

```
WinActivate % Ticket_Out,, xclude,
WinActivate, "00123456",, "00123456 | Salesforce - Google Chrome",
```

In the first one you force an expression in the first parameter correctly by starting the parameter off with a `%` followed up by a space. But then in the 3rd parameter you're in legacy syntax again and are just typing in `xclude`. This is going to be interpreted as literal text, and not a variable. Start that parameter also off with a `%` and a space.

And in the second one you're again not evaluating an expression on either of the parameters, so they're both interpreted as literal text. **Including the quotes**. In legacy syntax you don't quote strings since everything is already literal text by default.

```
WinActivate, % Ticket_Out, , % xclude 
WinActivate, % "00123456", , % "00123456 | Salesforce - Google Chrome"
```

Also removed the trailing commas you had. They don't belong there.
And now it should work, assuming the window titles and your [title match mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm) are in order.

---

Alternatively to using the exclude parameter, you could be more specific when specifying the window title.
For example you could make use of [`ahk_exe`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_exe) like this:

```
WinActivate, % "Title Of My Window ahk_exe chrome.exe"
```

And now you only match windows which come from a process named `chrome.exe`.

---

Overall, your trouble came mostly from not knowing the difference between legacy syntax and the modern expression syntax.
Here's a good documentation page to get you started on the differences:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm